# Getting interactive user input at terminal: provide prompt with editable default in racket

Tags: input, terminal, racket, readline

in bash, i can write a script which not only a) allows the user to input a string, but b) also prompts the user for a default value of that string, and c) allows that value to be edited before hitting enter:

```
#!/bin/bash
default_title="Another `date +%A` in paradise"
read -e -r -p "Title: " -i "${default_title}" input
title="${input:-default_title}"
echo "Title will be: ${title}"
```

how can I accomplish the same thing in Racket?

i can't see how to do it with racket's [read-line](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Byte_and_String_Input.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._read-line%29%29), which does let me read a line at the terminal (a), but does not let me provide a default value to the user (b) which they can then edit (c).

Comment: Why can't you check in the function- if it is a blank entry, provide a default value ?  What have you tried?

Comment: @mso: i) if i understand your 1st question correctly, my answer would be: because that's not the behavior i am looking for. try out the shell script and see how it works. having a function check for blank and then provide a default assumes the user already entered something. that's not how the shell script above works. it provides the default *first*, then lets the user *edit* that default, *then* submits it. thus, steps a, b, and c, as described.  ii) regarding your 2nd question: i have tried read-line, as mentioned, but i have not tried anything else, because i don't *know* what else to try.